# jQuery unwanted scroll up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a bunch of description blocks that are supposed to fade in when the corresponding image is clicked, fading out the previous one. Fading is working, but the page keeps scrolling up on each click, messing with the user's navigation.

```
google.load("jquery", "1.3");
google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
jQuery(function($) {

   $('#a').click(function(e){    
        $('#bio-b,#bio-c').fadeOut('slow', function(){
            $('#bio-a').fadeIn('slow');
        });
    });
});
});
```

I am a JavaScript/jQuery noob and mostly pieced this together from code found online. I hope the code is not all backwards.

edit: this is the HTML for image that would be clicked in this case :

```
<a href="#" id="a"><img></a>
```

description:

```
<article id="bio-a" class="bio"></article>
```

and the CSS (the description isn't displayed on loading the page)

```
#bio-a {
    display : none;
}
```

Any thoughts on what's causing this, how to fix it?

Comment: Not related to your problem but the id attribute has to start with a character not with a number.

Comment: @MarkusKottländer sorry, these are names in my code, but I put numbers in the example for readability. Will change back.

Comment: @nietonfir good suggestion, I hadn't thought of looking the version up. So would it be 2.0.3 ?
As for changing the href, I should have thought of that sooner but, I replaced it with an anchor to the description. Now not only does the page not scroll up on each click, it also scrolls right to the description ! It's even a better solution than Neikos's suggestion, thanks !

Comment: I created an answer for you to accept and upvote if you don't mind. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the `href="#"` attribute from the link, that might trigger a page scroll. This behaviour [is not defined](http://www.w3.org/Addressing/URL/4_2_Fragments.html) per se in the HTML standard, `<a href="#">` basically just points to a relative source and it's up to the browser vendor to implement the behaviour (some browsers may even reload the page). Most developers tend to use those elements because their either to lazy to set `cursor: pointer` on the element or have some legacy `onclick` handlers…

And do yourself a favor and use the latest possible version of jQuery (1.10 or 2.0, but don't forget to read the [disclaimer for jQuery 2.0](http://blog.jquery.com/2013/04/18/jquery-2-0-released/) before upgrading). ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Using an `href` of # effectively means to look for an element with an id of nothing. Obviously you do not have that. To fix the link of being 'followed' you need to call `preventDefault` on the event that gets passed to your handle.

I.e.:

```
$('#a').click(function(e){    
    $('#bio-b,#bio-c').fadeOut('slow', function(){
        $('#bio-a').fadeIn('slow');
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are looking for. If I understood you incorrectly please let me know and I'll adjust my answer :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('.image').click(function(){    
   var findIdNumber = $(this).attr("id");
   $('#bio-' + findIdNumber).fadeIn();
   $("article").not('#bio-'+findIdNumber).fadeOut();     
  });
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jmore009/cXr42/1/)